# How to rotate a line in KineticJS?

Tags: kineticjs

In KineticJS, I am trying to rotate a line on the onclick function.

```
var stage= new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: 'container',
    width: 500,
    height: 500
});

var layer= new Kinetic.Layer();

var redLine = new Kinetic.Line({
    points: [73, 70, 340, 23],
    stroke: 'red',
    strokeWidth: 15,
    draggable: true

  });
redLine.setOffsetX(73)    //its showing offset not a function
redLine.setOffsetY(70)
redLine.setAttrs({x:73,y:70});  

layer.add(redLine);
layer.draw();
var angle=0;
redLine.on('click',function(){
        angle=angle+0.1
        redLine.rotate(angle);
        layer.draw();
});

stage.add(layer);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct and it is working.

http://jsbin.com/perawi/1/edit?html,js,output

Remember by default kineticjs rotates by degrees. So 0.1 degrees is small value.